# getting following htaccess error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

in localhost server(easy php), htaccess file generation 505 error , here i have added the error log
.htaccess: Invalid command 'bbaw', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Invalid command 'css', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

```
htaccess file command:
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddCharset utf-8 .atom \
                         .bbaw \
                         .css \
                         .geojson \
                         .ics \
                         .js \
                         .json \
                         .jsonld \
                         .manifest \
                         .markdown \
                         .md \
                         .mjs \
                         .rdf \
                         .rss \
                         .topojson \
                         .vtt \
                         .webapp \
                         .webmanifest \
                         .xloc \
                         .xml
    </IfModule>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .bbaw .css .geojson .ics .js .json .jsonld .manifest .markdown .md .mjs .rdf .rss .topojson .vtt .webapp .webmanifest .xloc .xml
</IfModule>
```